# How to allocate multiple TPUs and adjust code to run on all of them

Tags: tensorflow, tpu

as a part of my R&D I was given access to multiple TPUs, but I can't find documentation how to allocate them together for my training purposes, both node-wise and code-wise. The documentation said `ctpu up -zone MY_ZONE_CHOICE` but this command allocates only single TPU. And, similar what changes should I add to my code if I want to use multiple TPUs? So far I've used this call `tf.contrib.cluster_resolver.TPUClusterResolver()` to check for TPU, what should be changed (if any) to check if I can access multiple TPUs?

Comment: Are multiple TPUs even supported?

Comment: TPU v3 pod provides a slot of TPUs. But I don't know if we can request multiple v2 TPUs at the same time and utilize them together for training. That's why I'm asking.

Comment: I agree with @Valentin. Even after 1 year since this question has been asked, it is not very easy to find any documentation regarding this